# How to find $_POST in a code with strstr

Tags: php, html, search

I'm attempting to find the `$_POST` variables in a line of code using `strstr`. Basically user submits a code, and my program searches to find `$_POST` in their code, of course `strstr` only finds the first occurrence but still. There is a simple HTML form that carries the code over to my PHP script. this is how I am doing it:

```
$user_submit=$_POST['submit'];//code posted
$post="$_POST";//used for post search
/*search code for $_POST*/

if(strstr($user_submit,$post)){
echo "found " . $post . ".";}
else{
echo "No " . $post . " found.";}
```

I am getting `No Array found.0` error. perhaps I am using `strstr` wrong, I am new to sifting through strings, all help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the HTML that you're using as well? The problem is a bit vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of variable substitution.  In PHP, including anything that looks like a variable identifier, such as $variable or $_POST, in a string literal will have its value substituted into the string.

So what's happening is $_POST in that string is getting replaced by PHP converting the $_POST variable to its string representation, which isn't $_POST and which is thus not matching anything.

You can use single quotes to avoid this, or I believe escaping the $ character.

Comment: yup that was it, for sure a push in the right direction. thank you so much

Comment: Reference: [strings in PHP](http://php.net/language.types.string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Form sended!
}
```

Comment: i see what you mean here, but im not trying to see if the variable is set, im trying to search through lines of code and single out $_POST variables.

Comment: Change: `$post="$_POST"` to `$post='$_POST'`